# Using LINQ to isolate a particular object from a list of objects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, linq, c#-3.0

[image]
<sub>(source: [yfrog.com](http://img707.yfrog.com/img707/6250/newpicturer.jpg))</sub>

I am trying my hand at making an invaders clone. there are 30 aliens arranged in a 5x 6 matrix on screen. I need to give the bottom most alien the ability to fire a shot.
I am using LINQ to group the aliens into 5 groups based on  Location.X and then sort the groups descending.I then need to choose one of the groups ( that gives me 5 groups)
and select the First alien in the group and use it;s coordinate to fire a shot.

My code below ,well ,works , but aliens in ANY row are merrily firing shots- not just the bottom most. Pl look at my code  below and tell me whats wrong.
(r = an instance of the Random class, all aliens are in a list called invaders).

```
 {
           var query = (from inv in invaders
                         group inv by inv.Location.X
                         into invgroup
                         orderby invgroup.Key descending 
                         select invgroup).ToList();

            var invfirst = query[r.Next(query.Count)].First();


                invaderShots.Add(new Shot(
                        new Point(invfirst.Area.X + invfirst.Area.Width / 2, invfirst.Area.Y + invfirst.Area.Height + 5),
                        displayrect, Shot.Direction.Down));

        }
```

EDIT:

Solved.Now it works as required after David B pushed me in the right direction.

Final code below. 
May definitely need some improvements in light of the large number of grouping/sorting going on. If anyone has something constructive to say on this I am all ears ( or eyes , in this case). Thanks to all who helped.

```
   List<Invader> firstinvader = invaders.GroupBy(inv => inv.Location.X)
                .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(inv => inv.Location.Y)).ElementAt(r.Next(5)).ToList();

            firstinvader.Sort(comparerByLocation);
            Invader item = firstinvader[firstinvader.Count -1];

            if(invaderShots.Count < 2)
            {
                invaderShots.Add(new Shot(
                     new Point(item.Area.X + item.Area.Width / 2, item.Area.Y + item.Area.Height / 2),
                     displayrect, Shot.Direction.Down));

            }
            else
            {
                return;

            }
```

Comment: @jonas Elfstrom : r is an instance of Random, I need to pull a random column from the group of 5 columns. ( game can become predictable otherwise)

Comment: @Midhat: how could you test it without the whole solution. If you mean the code compiles, sure it does. I have already stated above it works , just not doing what is "Required"

Comment: My Inavders are a bunch of buttons arranged in table layout. To simulate firing, I change the text of the button

Comment: here: http://www.4shared.com/file/TpQFNtH1/WindowsFormsApplication4.html

Comment: @midhat:Thanks for the file. downloaded and ran it. it does do what you say. But still does'nt solve my problem.

Comment: @dezkev Yes it wasnt meant to solve your problem. See if you can reproduce your problem in my project. Its all your code in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Invader> firstInvaders = invaders
  .GroupBy(inv => inv.Location.X)
  .Select(g => g
     .OrderByDescending(inv => inv.Location.Y)
     .First())
  .ToList();

Invader shooter = firstInvaders[r.Next(firstInvaders.Count)];
```

Comment: Tried this out too , does not work. What is happening is that aliens ( or invaders) in the first column ONLY are firing , but again arbitrarily- not the bottom most. So quite an improvement from my existing code , but still needs some tweaking.. will try my best.

Comment: after further tweaking, it now works.
See Edit in my original post for the final code.

Comment: Must be your X and Y are switched up.

Answer (score 1):

You're ordering the *groups* but not ordering the *invaders*. It's possible that this will do it:

```
var query = (from inv in invaders
             group inv by inv.Location.X
             into invgroup
             orderby invgroup.Key descending 
             select invgroup.OrderBy(inv => inv.Location.Y)).ToList();
```

(You may want to make the ordering descending, depending on whether Y is up or down.)

While this may work, I'm not sure that doing all this sorting all the time is ideal... can you not store the invaders in a data structure which helps you do this more easily?

Comment: Sorry! tried your code but that does'nt work either. Shots are still being fired from many different rows instead of from the bottom most row as required.

Comment: @dezkev: What's the difference between Location and Area in the invader class?

Comment: Location is a Point(X,Y) wher e the invader is drawn on screen and area is a property defined as below:
public Rectangle Area { get{return new Rectangle(Location,Image.Size);} }

Answer (score 1):

You are grouping by `Location.X`, which I am going to guess is the *column*. You then order these groups by the column number - note that this orders the *groups*, not the items within the groups. Since you then pick a random group, the fact that you ordered them is irrelevant. Once you have picked a random group - a random column of the original aliens - you then pick the `First` of the group, but since the aliens are not ordered *within* the groups, you are getting an arbitrary alien.

To fix this, you'll need to make sure that the *groups* are ordered by height (`Location.Y`, I guess), so that when you select the `First` of the group you pick randomly, it is the bottommost alien. Change

```
select invgroup).ToList();
```

to

```
select invgroup.OrderBy(inv => inv.Location.Y)).ToList();
```

(assuming your `Y` axis goes in the right direction for this to give what you want!)

Comment: Y axis is vertical. Maybe I need to order them after the random selection. How can i do that ?